# How to start node using four protocols

Tags: go-ethereum

What options to use to start the server with four protocols [eth/62], [eth/63], [les/1], [les/2]?

Now my node is working on three protocols : [eth/63] [les/1], [les/2]
I use next options: geth --cache 1024 --lightserv 25 console

I think that because of this my light client does not synchronize with my server.

About my Server Node:
Geth/v1.8.0
Windows 10 amd64